# LineString Heatmap with Open Layers 3

Tags: openlayers, geometry, linestring, heat-map, angularjs

I need to make a heatmap with a bunch of linestrings using AngularJS and Open Layers 3. I didn't find any examples, just a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56780705/creating-heatmap-in-openlayers-with-vector-source-containing-linestrings) answered here but that don't worked for me. In the question he do a action listener to when the features are added to the layer but for me, I already have all the features so I don't need this action. I've made some alterations to fit in my project structure, he don't show any errors but he don't show the heatmap either!
I have a service that creates all the layers on my map, I need this heatmap to be a layer, so that way I can set it visible or not.
LayerService:

```
/**
 * Routes is the list of routes that contains the linestring
 * inside the "geom" property.
 */
LayerService.routesHeatMap = function (routes, blur, radius) {
  const centroids = [];
  routes.forEach(route => {
    const geometry = route.geom;
    if (!!geometry) {
      const point_feature = new ol.Feature({ weight: route.expansion });
      point_feature.setGeometry(new ol.geom.LineString(geometry.coordinates));
      point_feature.setProperties({ projection: "EPSG:4326" });
      centroids.push(point_feature);
    }
  });
  let vector = new ol.layer.Heatmap({
    title: 'Routes. Heatmap',
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
      features: new ol.Collection(centroids),
      overlaps: true,
      opacity: 1,
      visible: false,
      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({
        dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326'
      })
    }),
    zIndex: 1,
    gradient: ['#007700', '#6ce200', '#efef00', '#ffff00', '#ff6600', '#ff0000'],
    blur: parseInt(blur.value, 10),
    radius: parseInt(radius.value, 10)
  });

  return vector;
};
```

My controller that have my map:

```
var blur = document.getElementById('blur');
var radius = document.getElementById('radius');
heat = LayerService.routesHeatMap(response, blur, radius);
vm.map.addLayer(heat);
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: When you say the other question doesn't work for you - what goes wrong? why doesn't it work?

Comment: I'll edit the question explainning that in the other question, he made a action listener to when the features are added to the layer, but in my case I already have all the features, so I don't need this listener, I tried the solution with a bunch of alterations to fit in my project and he didn't show any errors, but he didn't show my heatmap layer in the map either.